# How to handle `read` flag of notifications using React Native and Firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, notifications

I'm developing a mobile application using React Native and Firebase. I've stored my notifications in the Firebase Real-Time database. In my notifications screen, I retrieve the notifications and render them as a `Flatlist`.

I want to handle the `read` and `unread` status of each notification. What is the most efficient way to do this?

I've thought of a way like this. Each notification has a key as `read` which is `boolean`. When I write the notification data, it will be written as `read: false`. Once the user clicks on the notification, the `read` status will be updated to `true`.

Is there any other way which is more efficient to do this?

Please help me...